# Find the closure of the following

Tags: real-analysis

Hi I am trying to find the closure of $$A=\Big\{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{k}|n,k\in\mathbb{N}\Big\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$$ where $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard metric.

So to do that I know I have to find the accumulation point and I think $0$ is the only accumulation point which is not in $A$, so the closure would be $A\cup\{0\}$.

I am stuck with how to prove that $0$ is the only accumulation point.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: for fixed $n$, $(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence which is also contained in $A$.

Comment: There are a great deal of accumulation points, but the rest of them are already there, so the answer is indeed $A\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: @Thomas while going through some problems I found out that the closure A will be $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\}\cup A$. But I think the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\}\subseteq A$, Am I right?

Comment: Actually $n$ is not fixed but will cover all of $\mathbb{N}$, but yes, each $\frac{1}{n}$ is already an element of $A$, see the answer from Med.

Answer (score 1):

Limit points should be found. $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{k}$ gives a subset of rational numbers and you can find gaps between any two of them. If $x\neq0$, which is not in $A$, is assumed to be a limit point, we can always find an interval, with center $x$, that does not contain a member of $A$. Otherwise, $x$ becomes a limit to a sequence of $A$. However, $x=0$ is a limit point, for as $n$ and $k$ go to infinity, the fraction goes to $0$ and consequently, an open interval, with center $0$, always contain an element of $A$. Therefore, the closure of $A$ is $A+\{0\}$.